# vue-gtag is not tracking

Tags: vue.js, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I'm trying to track all visited page in my vuejs App, but is not working.

**main.ts**

```
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag';
    
Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: process.env.VUE_APP_GA },
  enabled: false
}, router);

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Also I try to add an event in the header, but is not working anyway.

```
this.$gtag.pageview("/about");
this.$gtag.event('header', { 
  'event_label': 'header',
  'event_category': 'test',
  value: 1
});
```

I'm using Vue version `2.6.11` and `vue-gtag 1.6.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove line:

```
enabled: false
```

From official document [link](https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/v/master/opt-in-out)

The plugin will immediately start tracking, but it is possible to disable the plugin at start by set enabled: false

Comment: You should explain your answer, otherwise it is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Yes, now is working deleting that. Thanks!